# Issue with CFX_image tag

Tags: image, image-processing, coldfusion

In CF8 I had a 32 bit compiler that generated a captcha. That worked great until I flipped to a 64 bit system. The DLL had a 500 error, so I installed cfx_openimage. Now it does work. However many of the letters/numbers in the 4 and 5th position are scaled down so small you cant even read it . It literally just needs to display what the pre-made gif, that is pulled from a folder called P_codes contains, but no scaling of certain letters... just as-is. I can't seem to get this to work.

Here is the code that calls the image. Any ideas??

```
<CFSET var.codenum = RandRange(60466176, 2147483647)>
<CFSET var.passcode = ucase(replace(replace(toString(formatBaseN(var.codenum, 36)),"0","P","ALL"),"o","J","ALL"))>

<CFSET imgName = createUUID()&'.gif'>
<CFSET line1 = "0,#randRange(0,30)#,140,#randRange(0,35)#">
<CFSET line2 = "0,#randRange(0,40)#,140,#randRange(0,40)#">
<CFSET line3 = "0,#randRange(5,45)#,140,#randRange(10,45)#">
<CFSET line4 = "0,#randRange(10,50)#,140,#randRange(20,50)#">
<CFSET line5 = "0,#randRange(20,50)#,140,#randRange(20,50)#">

<CFSET pos1 = randRange(1,24)>
<CFSET pos2 = randRange(1,24)>
<CFSET pos3 = randRange(1,24)>
<CFSET pos4 = randRange(1,24)>
<CFSET pos5 = randRange(1,24)>
<CFSET pos6 = randRange(1,24)>

<CFSET bgcolor = "#formatBaseN(randRange(80,210),16)##formatBaseN(randRange(80,210),16)##formatBaseN(randRange(80,210),16)#">

<CFX_IMAGE ACTION="IML"
    FILE="NEW"
    X="140"
    Y="50"
    BGCOLOR="#bgcolor#"
    COMMANDS="
    setfontantialias
    setfont 19,0,0,bold,Verdana
    ##setbrushsize 200
    line #line1#,000000
    line #line2#,000000
    line #line3#,000000
    line #line4#,000000
    line #line5#,000000

    text 0,#pos1#,20,50,000000,#mid(var.passcode,1,1)#
    text 25,#pos2#,40,50,000000,#mid(var.passcode,2,1)#
    text 49,#pos3#,60,50,000000,#mid(var.passcode,3,1)#
    text 73,#pos4#,80,50,000000,#mid(var.passcode,4,1)#
    text 97,#pos5#,100,50,000000,#mid(var.passcode,5,1)#
    text 121,#pos6#,120,50,000000,#mid(var.passcode,6,1)#
    write #expandPath('./_pcodes/')##imgName#
">
<!--- <cfoutput><img src="#imgname#"></cfoutput> --->
<!--- <cfcontent type="image/gif" file="#expandPath('./')##imgName#" deletefile="Yes"> --->
```

Comment: Care to share? :) Posting the solution as an "answer" will help the next guy.

Comment: see the above code that has the 6 lines that begin with "text" followed by the numbers 20, 40, 60, 80 and 120? Those dictate the font size. Just bump those numbers up and voila' :-)

Comment: Ah. Go ahead and use the "Post Your Answer" option, so it is easier for others to find (Answering your own question is allowed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> text 0,#pos1#,20,50,000000,#mid(var.passcode,1,1)#
> text 25,#pos2#,40,50,000000,#mid(var.passcode,2,1)#
> text 49,#pos3#,60,50,000000,#mid(var.passcode,3,1)#
> text 73,#pos4#,80,50,000000,#mid(var.passcode,4,1)#
> ...
> ```

See the above code that has the 6 lines that begin with "text" followed by the numbers 20, 40, 60, 80 and 120? Those dictate the font size. Just bump those numbers up and voila' :-)